# Evaluate the image of complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Given the function $f:\mathbb{C}\setminus\{-i\}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}\setminus \{1\}$, defined by $f(z)=\frac{z-i}{z+i}$.

I'm supposed to find the image for $f(\{z\mid\Im (z) > 0\})$. However I'm fairly uncertain on how to do this.

I know that $z = \frac{-(a+1)i}{a-1}$ for some $a\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{1\}$, and i've tried writing z on the form $n+im$ for $n,m\in\mathbb{R}$, but that doesn't help me.

Any suggestions on how to solve it?

Comment: It is a Mobius transform. It should map a half-space to either a half-space, ball, or complement of a ball. Maybe start by mapping three points on the boundary, and finding the unique circle or line that passes through their images?

Comment: The course just started so we haven't learned about Mobius transforms yet. I'll look it up and see if it's useful, thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** With $z=x+iy$ simplify
$$u+iv=\dfrac{z-i}{z+i}$$
where $w=u+iv$ is in the range of map. Then find
$$1-u^2-v^2=((1-u)^2+v^2)y>0$$
which gives the result.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, how does the last relation make sense?

Comment: means $u^2+v^2<1$.

Comment: note that $(1-u)^2+v^2$ and $y$ are positive.

Comment: Yes I can see that, my problem is how to get from $u+iv=\frac{x+iy-i}{x+iy+i}$ to $1-u^2-v^2=((1-u)^2+v^2)y$

Comment: simplify $(u+iv)(x+iy+i)=x+iy-i$ and consider real part and imaginary of both sides.

Comment: So far I'm dealing with the equations $uy+vx+u = y-1$ and $x=u x-v y-v$. I'm I on the right track?

Comment: of course, drop $x$ between them.

Comment: I've got it now. Thank you so much for your help and patience!

Comment: you are welcome dear.